# How to stop requests after a download

Tags: python-3.x

I want to download a m3u file but I get a 404 error how once the download is complete the execution stops it's up to you to say return or break in the python language in the code the download is complete but another request is launched

```
LINKFILE= '/tmp/link'
M3UPATH= '/tmp/IPTVWORLD47.m3u'


def create_bouquet():
    if not os.path.exists(M3UPATH):
        os.system('curl  --limit-rate 100K     -s -k -Lbk -A -k -m 8 -m 52 %s -o %s > /dev/null 2>&1' % (url, M3UPATH)) 
        time.sleep(180)
        os.system('wget --secure-protocol=TLSv1_2 --no-check-certificate -q -O- --trust-server-names %s > %s' % (url, M3UPATH))
        with open(M3UPATH, "r") as f:
            sdata = f.read()
            if "UHD" in sdata:
                print("Target Found !!!")
            elif not "FHD" in sdata: 
               time.sleep(60)
               os.system('wget --secure-protocol=TLSv1_2 --no-check-certificate -q -O- --trust-server-names %s > %s' % (url, M3UPATH))
               with open(M3UPATH, "r") as f:
                   sdata = f.read()
                   if "UHD" in sdata:
                       print("Target Found !!!")
                       time.sleep(60)
                       os.system('wget --secure-protocol=TLSv1_2 --no-check-certificate -q -O- --trust-server-names %s > %s' % (url, M3UPATH))

                   else:
                       print('nada_link')
                       return 'nada_link'
```